# Lazy Loading Infinite Scroll in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, infinite-scroll

I perform the data fetching by using a stored procedure which accepts page size, and page index.

I would like to be able to call the action method List from the view with the page size and page index parameters, which in turn will call the stored procedure.

That is doable. But I'm trying to do this with jquery lazy loading.

So, the view will first fetch the results in the first page (let's say page size = 10 and page index = 1). Next, if the user scrolls down, the next page will be fetched, which means the view will call the the List method with page size = 20 and page index = 1. this will countinue until all the pages from the results were fetched.

Is this scenario reasonable, and if so how do Implement it using jquery? if this scenario is not reasonable, what are the other options?

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult List(int pageSize, int pageIndex)
    { ... }
```

The jquery I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-button").click(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("List", "Home")';
        url = url + "?pageSize=10&pageIndex=1";
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $('#listcontainer').fadeOut(0, function () {
                $('#listcontainer').html(data);
                $('#listcontainer').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
    });
});
```